# Conditionalish/joint probability?

Tags: probability

What is the overall probability of some event happening if it has 15% chance of happening, but can only happen if another event with 40% of happening takes place ?

Comment: You should be careful how you phrase the question.  As you have it stated you could say that the event has 15 percent of occurring since that’s what you state at outset. But assuming you meant 15 percent of happening if the second event occurs then please refer to answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0.40*0.15=0.06.   So, for the event 2nd to occur you need the 1st to occur.  So 60 percent of time neither occurs.   Of the remaining 40 percent 15 percent of time the second occurs.  Ie 6 percent of total

Comment: Thank you, that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the occurrence that an event happens, and let $B$ be the condition. 
Then $$P(A|B) = \frac{P( A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$

Hence: $0,15 \cdot 0,4 = 0,6$, therefore $6$%